# Issue with .appendTo, text moving to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My website is using a Bootstrap set-up to isolate profile pictures from one another.

There is a description `<div>` block above the three profiles.

Each of the profiles are equally using a `<div>` block of col-sm-4 col-lg-4" across the entire website.

Together, the description `<div>` and the profiles `<div>` are collected into a `<div class="container-fluid">`

The profile picture and name are centered in each of the three segments.

The idea is when a visitor clicks the profile, the selected profile moves into the description `<div>` box, (hiding the text present via `.hide()`) and displays the profile and a short biography on the individual. It returns to its previous position in the profile  when selected again, or if another profile is selected.

The Javascript formula has been duplicated three times to ensure that the profiles return to their original positions once the visitor has deselected the current profile, or selected another profile.

It works... sort of. Eventually, the profiles perform as the script is intended for it to do, with a minor setback that I cannot understand how to fix.

**Issue:**

Each time a profile `<div>` is first clicked, the name and picture in the selected profile SHIFTS from the center to the left-side wall of their box.

It requires an additional click to run the javascript function to move the selected profile into the description `<div>` box.

It returns to its original position when clicked again, but with the name and picture still against the left-side wall of their  box, like when first clicked.

The Javascript code for one profile is below:

```
function moveButton1(elem){
"use strict";

    if ($(elem).parent().attr("id") === "nsb")
    {
        $("#leadintro").hide();
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('#selected');
        $("#barberoinfo").fadeIn();
    }

    else
    {
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('#nsb');
        $("#leadintro").show(); 
    }
}
```

Table of Contents:

- nsb = `<div>` containing the profile name and picture
- Leadintro = description of the sub-site
- selected = the container-fluid `<div>` box where the nsb's move into to display profile information

**Question:**

How do I fix stopping the profile `<div>` shift of its content to the left and having only one click to start the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

I had 4  `<div class="row text-center`> at each the description and three profiles.

After removing three of them, leaving only one to circle overall, it is working fine.

-